# Default/Mixin Generic In java

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering if i can replace the generic type upon class initialization ( without inheritance ).
The case is as below .
I have bunch of generic actor + builder class in my module and distribute this to people who wants to use it in my team while keeping the actor and the entry point of fluent interface generic.

The requirement is how can people supply their own builder ( not extending ) to do the stuff they want.

Current state:

```java
class MessageBuilder {
    public MessageBuilder msg(String msg) {
        //do something
    }
}

class Actor {        
    public MessageBuilder newMessage() {
        return new MessageBuilder();
    }
}

class Main {            
    @Test
    public void testActor() {
        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.newMessage().msg("sss").send();
    } 
}
```

Desired state:

```java
class MessageBuilder{    
    public MessageBuilder msg(String msg) {
        //do something
    }

    //more fluent api...    
}

// project specific - dont want to extend from generic one as this should be contains its own fluent interface
class MyCustomMessageBuilder {
    public MyCustomMessageBuilder rawstr(String rawstr) {
        //do something
    }
}

class Actor<T> {
    public T newMessage() {
        return (T)builderFactory.getInstance();
    }
}

class Main {            
    @Test
    public void testActor() {
        Actor<MyCustomMessageBuilder> actor = new Actor(BuilderFactory);
        actor.newMessage().rawstr("sss").send();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without some known tricks.

First, Java implements Generics with [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) ([more information on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20erasure?)), therefore the compiler will:

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

In practice, this means that `Actor<Builder1>` and `Actor<Builder2>` are the exact same class after it gets compiled. In both cases, `newMessage` is implemented as follows:

```java
class Actor {
    public Object newMessage() {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's not possible for `newMessage` to have different implementations based on the type parameter and it's not possible for `newMessage` to ask for the type of `T` because it gets removed.

Having said that, you can pass in type information:

```java
class Actor<T> {
    private Class<T> klass;

    public Actor(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    public T newMessage() {
        return klass.newInstance();
    }
}

class Main {
    @Test
    public void testActor() {
        Actor<MyCustomMessageBuilder> actor = new Actor<>(MyCustomMessageBuilder.class);
        actor.newMessage().rawstr("sss").send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. This will work but will enforce everybody to supply the class definition regardless if they still want to opt with default ( which is CustomBuilder ) . Seems we can provide default with java generics

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a factory approach. The builder should be supplied by a factory:

```
class Actor<MsgBuilder> {
    private final Supplier<MsgBuilder> messageBuilderFactory;

    public Actor(Supplier<MsgBuilder> builderFactory) {
        this.messageBuilderFactory = builderFactory;
    }

    public MsgBuilder newMessage() {
        return messageBuilderFactory.get();
    }
}
```

This way offers flexibility in creating the message builder without sacrificing type safety and also no need for ugly casting.